# Function `feof` Always Returns 1

Tags: c++, c, file-io, visual-studio-2015, feof

I'm trying to read in a binary file of size 114,808 bytes.  I allocate memory for the file, and then try to read in the file using `fopen` and `fread`.  The first time `fread` is called, it always reads in 274 bytes, and the subsequent call to `feof` always returns 1, even though clearly the end of the file has not been reached.  Why is this?

According to the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(stdio%2Ffeof);k(feof);k(DevLang-C%2B%2B);k(TargetOS-Windows)&rd=true) for `feof`, "The **feof** function returns a nonzero value if a read operation has attempted to read past the end of the file; it returns 0 otherwise."  So I don't understand what is causing `feof` to consistently return 1.

Here's the code that I have so far.  Any help would be much appreciated.  Thanks!

```
// Open source file with read-only access
if ( iError == ERROR_SUCCESS )
{
    #ifdef _MSC_VER
    #pragma warning(disable : 4996)
    #endif
    pFile = fopen( pSrcPath, "r" );

    if ( pFile == NULL )
    {
        iError = ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND;
    }
}

// Read in source file to memory
if ( iError == ERROR_SUCCESS )
{
    do
    {
        // Buffer pointer passed to fread will be the file buffer, plus the
        //  number of bytes actually read thus far.
        iSize = fread( pFileBuf + iActReadSz, 1, iReqReadSz, pFile );
        iError = ferror( pFile );   // check for error
        iEndOfFile = feof( pFile ); // check for end of file

        if ( iError != 0 )
        {
            iError = ERROR_READ_FAULT;
        }
        else if ( iEndOfFile != 0 )
        {
            // Read operation attempted to read past the end of the file.
            fprintf( stderr,
                "Read operation attempted to read past the end of the file. %s: %s\n",
                pSrcPath, strerror(errno) );
        }
        else
        {
            iError = ERROR_SUCCESS; // reset error flag
            iActReadSz += iSize;    // increment actual size read
            iReqReadSz -= iSize;    // decrement requested read size
        }
    }
    while ((iEndOfFile == 0) && (iError == ERROR_SUCCESS));
}

// Close source file
if ( pFile != NULL )
{
    fclose( pFile );
}
```

FYI, I'm trying to write this, so that the source is more-or-less compatible with C, even though MSVS basically forces you into a C++ environment.

Comment: You're not reading a binary file; you're reading a text file.  A binary file is opened with `pFile = fopen(pSrcPath, "rb");`.  What's probably happening is that there's a byte 0x1A or 032 or 26 or control-Z that is making the text processing logic interpret it as EOF.

Comment: "... source is more-or-less compatible with C ..." Either it **is** compatible or it is **not**. There is no "a little bit pregnant". You will have to decide once you allocate memory.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You didn't include "b" in the mode string for fopen. On MS Windows, opening a file in text mode will result in (among other things that you don't usually want happening when reading a binary file) it detecting an EOF whenever it reaches a byte with the value 0x1A.